# get website's All pages including HTML,ASPX etc in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am making an application
which will return all pages (with there HTMl) of given website's URl. using this code it is working fine.

```
  foreach (string links in Find(htmlCode))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(links);
        string chk = "";
        if (link != null)
        {
            chk = client.DownloadString(link);
        }}
```

But so far I got access only those pages of Website which href or link is available in HTML of web.
I can't get access other pages of web which href is not mentioned in website 
How can I access those pages?

an example of the Facebook pages
Can I access all the facebook pages?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the page isn't linked to, you won't be able to find it. If you are crawling, you should also respect the [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file.